# ftputil: listdir returns an empty list even though the directory is not empty

Tags: python, listdir, ftputil

I want to use `ftputil` instead of `ftplib` in python.
On a public ftp server everything works fine with both libraries:

```
host = 'ftp.avm.de'
user = 'anonymous'
passwd = ''


import ftputil
with ftputil.FTPHost(host, user, passwd) as ftp:
    print(ftp.getcwd(), ftp.listdir('.'))


import ftplib
with ftplib.FTP(host, user, passwd) as ftp:
    print(ftp.pwd(), ftp.nlst('.'))
```

output:

```
/ ['archive', 'fritzbox', 'fritzpowerline', 'fritzwlan']
/ ['archive', 'fritzbox', 'fritzpowerline', 'fritzwlan']
```

If I do it on a ftp server (Windows CE6) in my local network, the output of `ftputil` is empty while `ftplib` correctly lists all files:

```
/ []
/ ['1', '2', '3']
```

What am i missing?

Comment: try add  `print(ftp.pwd())`  to both test.

Comment: What FTP server are you running? How is it configured? Since it's local, you can presumably log the commands, so what is `ftputil` sending that's different from `ftplib`?

Answer (score 4):

The observation above could be because of https://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac/ticket/110. Directories and files will be missing from the `FTPHost.listdir` result if the FTP server doesn't understand the `-a` option for listing hidden directories and files and interprets the option as a directory or file to list.

Try setting `use_list_a_option` to `False` after creating the `FTPHost` instance:

```
ftp_host = ftputil.FTPHost(host, user, password)
ftp_host.use_list_a_option = False
# Use ftp_host as before.
...
```

In a future ftputil version 4.x, `use_list_a_option` will default to `False` to avoid this problem (see the linked ticket). I didn't want to make this change earlier in a bugfix release because this is a backward-incompatible change and may break currently working code.

Comment: it seems that the DeprecationWarning is displayed regardless if `use_list_a_option` is used explicitly or not. Any way to mute it? (and thanks for the wonderful library!)

Comment: @zerohedge Emitting the warning only on access would require a property instead of a simple attribute and I think making the attribute a property only for the `DeprecationWarning` is a bit over the top. :)

Comment: @zerohedge You can silence the `DeprecationWarning` with Python's warning infrastructure, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html , especially the `filterwarnings` function, https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings .

Comment: @zerohedge Thanks for the compliment! This is really helpful for my motivation to work on ftputil. :-)